# jQuery text effect where words appear one by one

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-animate

I was asked if I could come up with a text effect in HTML using jQuery where I get a string and then the routine automatically detects the words and animates each word in, one at a time.

Like.

1. sec into the animation shows: "Happy"
2. sec into the animation shows:"Happy New"
3. sec into the animation shows:"Happy New Year"
4. sec into the animation shows:"Happy New Year 2011"

each word should "fade/animate" in slowly, I thought a simple sliding pane going right in pixels would be satisfying - but no. Word by word.

I could need some ideas on this one. I know some jQuery and a lot of Javascript, so I guess I need a bit of help with the jQuery part.

For the list of words, I would just split on " " (whitespace) and accept that ",.!" etc are part of a word.

But how do I animate this "dynamic array" in jQuery - is there a plugin somewhere or am I the first?

I was thinking that perhaps a bulleted list could be the trick too, then make it float horizontally like a menu and then add the word as a new bullet, once per second. But I am excited to see what the experts in here come up with for solution. :O)

**EDIT**
From the marked answer, I've this:

```
    var str = $('div#greeting h1').html(); // grab text
    $('div#welcome h1').html(""); // clear text

    var spans = '<span>' + str.split(" ").join(' </span><span>') + '</span>';
    $(spans).hide().appendTo('div#greeting h1').each(function(i)
    {
        $(this).delay(500 * i).fadeIn();
    });
```

The STRONG tag works, but somehow parts of the text fades in a group.

Try this:
"here is a test text. [strong]We believe this is better[/strong] than ever." and see the problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/TcdQb/

```
var str = $('span.ticker').text();

var spans = '<span>' + str.split(/\s+/).join(' </span><span>') + '</span>';

$(spans).hide().appendTo('body').each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(1000 * i).fadeIn();
});
```

- This places the words in span tags: `"<span>Happy </span><span>New </span><span>Year </span><span>2011</span>"`
- Creates DOM elements: [`$(spans)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2)
- Hides them: [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)
- Appends them: [`.appendTo('body')`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/)
- Finally, iterates over them using [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), and [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) the [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) of each one by 1000ms multiplied by the current index of the iteration.

---

**EDIT:** Here's an update to the example that uses a shorter delay, and a longer animation, so the animations overlap a little.

http://jsfiddle.net/TcdQb/1/

```
    $(this).delay(400 * i).fadeIn(1000);
```

---

**EDIT:** To deal with nested tags (one level deep only) you could do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/WgMrz/

```
var h1 = $('div#greeting h1');

h1.hide().contents().each(function() {
    var words;
    if (this.nodeType === 3) {
        words = '<span> ' + this.data.split(/\s+/).join(' </span><span> ') + ' </span>';
        $(this).replaceWith(words);
    } else if (this.nodeType === 1) {
        this.innerHTML = '<span> ' + this.innerHTML.split(/\s+/).join(' </span><span> ') + ' </span>';
    }
});

   // Remove any empty spans that were added
h1.find('span').hide().each(function() {
    if( !$.trim(this.innerHTML) ) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});

h1.show().find('span').each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(400 * i).fadeIn(600);
});
```

Comment: very good too! now I have to decide who should have the "answer".. wish I could mark more than one...

Comment: How would I initialize the str variable from lets say a span/div with a css class called eg. "ticker": <span class="ticker">Happy New Year 2011</span>

Comment: @BerggreenDK: Pretty simple. I'll update my answer in a minute. EDIT: Updated. I change the first line of code to `var str = $('span.ticker').text();`.

Comment: LOL! I really need to get more jQuery experience. This rocks! Thanks a lot!

Comment: ohh no, they want to use STRONG on some of the words. Any ideas?

Comment: @BerggreenDK: Do you mean on some *random* words, or on specific ones. And are the STRONG words like that on the page originally, or is it being added?

Comment: currently, its have of the words tagged into one strong..I'ved added my attempt in my question. :o)

Comment: somehow the function adds [span style="display:block"] on every word in the greeting in Firefox??? cant override it... strange.

Comment: @BerggreenDK: Just noticed your comments. I'll take another look. (By the way, with `split(/\s+/)` you're passing a regular express that says *"split whereever one or more adjacent space characters are found"*.

Comment: @BerggreenDK: [Here's an updated example.](http://jsfiddle.net/WgMrz/) It will only work for tags nested one level deep. I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: @Patrick dw: you are AMAZING!!! :o) thanks now it works with Firefox too. A bit more complex script, but it works. Trying to figure out what you did with nodeType etc. but thats my problem of curiosity.

Comment: @BerggreenDK: It is used to distinguish between a text node and an element, since you need a little different technique to manipulate their content. [Here's a list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType) of the different node types. Types 1 and 3 are the most likely that you'll need to reference. The `.contents()` method is similar to `.children()` except that it also retrieves text nodes. So when we iterate using `.each()`, we test each one to see which we currently have.

Comment: @Patrick dw: cool with the extra explanation, thumbs up from me!

Comment: if i have to so the same with bullets, then it doesn't work.How should it be done?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an expert, but maybe you're overthinking this.  How about:

```
   var fadeWordsIn = function(elem$) {
      var txt = elem$.text().split(' ');
      elem$.empty();
      var pushIt = function() {
          if (txt.length) {
              var word = txt.shift();
              var span$ = $("<span>" + word + " </span>");
              elem$.append(span$);
              span$.hide().fadeIn(1000, pushIt);
          }
       };
       pushIt();
  };
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was aiming for.

Answer (score 1):

You want the "BlockFadeIn by word" animation here: http://dev.seankoole.com/jquery/ui-effect/text.html

Just released!

Comment: D'oh.  Much better answer than mine.  My fault for using Emacs instead of Google.

Comment: Thats an awesome page with loads of interesting samples too. But I think the right answer gotta be the one being most precise this time. Thanks for the link though. Cool stuff!

Comment: @Malvolio: I think you did a good attempt and I am sorry that I cant mark more than one good answer, but I've voted yours up too.

Comment: The link is dead