# Function in jQuery to loop over elements and show/hide?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string, I want to split it into a group of `<p>` elements, create a function to show/hide each one on a delay, and then rerun the function if a user presses the button.

So far I take the string and split it into the result `<p>` but my efforts to loop over them and show/hide each one on delay hasn't been successful.

[Here's a fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/0771uxq9/1/)

HTML:

```
<div>
    <span>Hello! Lorem ipsom dolor set amit.</span>
    <div class="result"></div>
</div>
<button>Run</button>
```

Js:

```
var words = $("span").text();
var split = words.split(" ");
for(var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    $(".result").append("<p>" + split[i] + "</p>");
};
```

In short: I want it to look like:

```
<p1>.show(1000) -> <p1>.hide() <p2>.show(1000) -> <p2>.hide() <p3>.show(1000)...
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607613/jquery-text-effect-where-words-appear-one-by-one

Comment: sounds like a job for angularjs and ng-repeat and ng-show :)

Comment: I'm actually certain it's written in angular already. What I'm doing is just a quick proof of concept so I don't care how pretty it is. It's never going to be used for anything other than a quick display.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.queue()` , `.fadeIn()` , `.fadeOut()`

```js
var words = $("span").text(), result = $(".result")
, split = words.split(" ");
for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
  result.append("<p style=display:none;padding:2px;> " + split[i] + " </p>");
};
$("button").click(function() {
  if (result.queue("cycle").length === 0) {
    result.queue("cycle", $.map($("> p", result), function(el, i) {
      return function(next) {
        $(el).fadeIn(1000, function() {
          $(this).fadeOut(next)
        })
      }
    })).dequeue("cycle")
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>Hello! Lorem ipsom dolor set amit.</span>
  <div class="result"></div>
</div>
<button>Run</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to do it with jQuery promises:

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('.result').empty(); //reset
  var words = $("span").text();
  var split = words.split(" ");
  for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    var p = $("<p>" + split[i] + "</p>");
    p.appendTo('.result');
  };

  var p = $.Deferred().resolve().promise();
  $('.result p').each(function(i, par) {
    var $par = $(par);
    p = p.then(function() {
      $par.show(500).delay(500).hide(500);
      return $par.promise();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.result {
  height: 20px;
  }

.result p {
  margin: 0px;
  display : none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>Hello! Lorem ipsom dolor set amit.</span>
  <div class="result"></div>
</div>
<button>Run</button>
```